# Make [exchange2007] a synonym for [exchange-2007] and merge

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

There are 4 question tagged [exchange-2007](/questions/tagged/exchange-2007) and 72 tagged [exchange2007](/questions/tagged/exchange2007) on SO.
I could change the 4 questions but to maintain symmetry with [exchange-2003](/questions/tagged/exchange-2003), I would suggest to change the other 72 questions.

Probably no matter if there is a synonym anyway...